# Subclassing Objective-C class with factory method in Swift, the generics doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, swift, generics

I have a Base class with a factory method written in Objective-C.(some lib)

```
@interface Base : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *content;
+ (instancetype)baseWithContent:(NSString *)content;
@end
//==================
@implementation Base
+ (instancetype)baseWithContent:(NSString *)content {
    Base* base = [[Base alloc]init];
    base.content = content;
    return base;
}
@end
```

Then I subclassing it in swift and casting it into AnyObject.(ignore the Bridging-Header part)

```
class Child: Base {}
var c = Child(content: "Child")
print("before casting", type(of:c))
print("after casting", type(of:c as AnyObject))
```

Get this strange result that **it become a Base after casting.**

```
before casting Optional<Child>
after casting Base
```

Actually if i use a designated initializer to override the generated-convenience initializer from objective-c, I get the right result.

```
class Child: Base {
    init?(content:String) {
        super.init()
        self.content = content
    }
}

before casting Optional<Child>
after casting Child
```

Am I making any mistake? Thanks for answering.
I'm using Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62) and Swift 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your factory method implementation in Obj-C is wrong. It always creates an instance of `Base`. To fix it:

```
+ (instancetype)baseWithContent:(NSString *)content {
    Base *base = [[self alloc] init]; //self instead of Base
    base.content = content;
    return base;
}
```

Basically, your factory method implementation doesn't match its return type, the result are type problems in Swift because Swift trusts type declarations.

Comment: Thanks! I see. "Swift trusts type declarations"...  How can I subclassing that Obj-C class and use its initializer without changing the implementation? I can't change the implementation since it's a third party lib.

Comment: The type problem, Is it a bug of swift?

Comment: @Yang Nope, it's a bug in the Objective-C code. If you want to subclass, avoid calling that method.

Comment: Thanks again! But what's inside the instance if the SubClass also has some store properties? Will it leak the memory when down casting? Not familiar with the swift object model :(

Comment: @Yang: Not sure what you mean by "what's inside the instance if the SubClass also has some store properties". There is only one instance. Every instance has a class fixed at when it is created. When created using the incorrect code the instance is a `Base`. What compile-time types of variables you have (which may be wrong in this case) and how you cast them have no effect on the actual runtime class of the object. The object model here is the same in Swift as in Objective-C. Everything here applies to Objective-C.